# R ggplot2 fonts issue

Tags: r, fonts, ggplot2

I'm trying to get the xkcd fonts working in R with ggplot2. However I'm running into some issues.
Here is what I have done so far.
1) Installed the "Humor Sans" font from the xkcd site in the directory ~/.fonts
2) Installed the "extrafont" package. This installation worked smoothly.
3) Load the library

```
library(extrafont)
```

However when I try to import the font I get the following error.

```
> font_import(pattern="Humor Sans")
 Importing fonts may take a few minutes, depending on the number of fonts and the speed of the system.
 Continue? [y/n] y
 Scanning ttf files in /usr/share/fonts/, ~/.fonts/ ...
 Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
 Error in data.frame(fontfile = ttfiles, FontName = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
 arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong or what else I should be doing?
Thanks much in advance

edit: Running ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
font_import(paths = "~/.fonts", pattern="Humor Sans")
```

It does not appear to me that "~/.fonts" is the default font folder for a Mac, so if that is (or is not) your OS, you should include more details when you edit your original question.

Comment: Running Ubuntu 12.04. That didn't fix the problem. Besides it is already scanning that directory per the error message

Comment: Then you should display the results of ls on that directory. The error message is also saying nothing matched the pattern.

Comment: The directory ~/.fonts has just the Humor-Sans.ttf file.

Comment: Well, if it is spelled "Humor-Sans" then that would explain why a pattern of "Humor Sans" wasn't finding it.